# Does Akarat's Champion death-preventing effect actually work or is it bugged?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am trying to find out if I can rely on the death-preventing effect of Akarat's Champion. I have read in several places online that it is possibly bugged, and it seemed to have been confirmed. However, I am thinking that perhaps it worked for them, but it wore off right when they died and made it seem like it didn't work.

Can anyone confirm whether this is a bug or not?

Several links pertaining to this discussion are below.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/22c8tg/crusader_akarats_champion_game_breaking_thorns_bug/

http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-class-forums/crusader-the-church-of-zakarum/83448-akarats-champion-bug

http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-class-forums/crusader-the-church-of-zakarum/87084-akarats-champion

Several others as well.

Comment: Can you provide a link as to where they say it's bugged?  And how?

Comment: I'm not sure how we can answer this; the best we can do is say, "Yes, this is how it's working", or, "No, it doesn't do this."  We might be able to *guess* it might not work as intended, but we can't give a definitive answer yes or no.

Comment: I'm guessing he's talking about Akarat's Champion death-preventing effect. Wrath regeneration and attack speed do work, obviously.

Comment: I re-wrote it to make more sense, as you described. Sorry I wasn't clear in the first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#crusader). [Akarat's Champion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/active/akarats-champion) has been re-worked.

It no longer has the original death prevention ability. Now you have to have the [Prophet](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/active/akarats-champion) rune to gain that ability.

The patch mentions nothing about fixing a bug with this ability. However, since they have re-worked the skill, this may have affected the bugs that are mentioned in your post.